# Mutltiple check conditions fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to redirect to root_path if one of this conditions is true :

1. current_user is not present
2. current_user is not an admin OR a professional

   ```
   def check_user_pro!
     if @current_user.present?
       if !@current_user.is_admin || !@current_user.profile.professional?
         redirect_to(root_path)
         flash.alert = "Reserved"
       end
     else
       redirect_to(root_path)
       flash.alert = "Reserved"
     end
   end
   ```

Comment: `redirect_to(root_path, alert: "Reserved") unless current_user&.is_admin || current_user&.profile&.professional?`

Comment: `redirect_to(root_path, alert: "Reserved") unless current_user.present? && (current_user.is_admin || current_user.profile.professional?)`